# MySQL INSERT INTO results in Unknown Column in Field List

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using the SQL feature phpMyAdmin to add 1 single record into my table.  For simplicity, the record will be blank except for the 'symbol' field.

**Table structure:**

token_id = auto-increment, primary key

symbol = varchar(255)

every thing else is set to allow *null* entires, so should be irrelevant

I have tried the following queries, but all result in the same error:
unknown column 'symbol' in 'field list'

**What I have tried:**

```
INSERT INTO tokens (symbol) VALUES ('XYZ');

INSERT INTO tokens (symbol) VALUES ("XYZ");

INSERT INTO tokens (symbol) VALUES (XYZ);

INSERT INTO tokens.symbol VALUES ('XYZ');

INSERT INTO `tokens`.`symbol` VALUES ('XYZ');
```

Any suggestions?

Just for reference, trying the INSERT and using all columns and setting them to *null* results in the same exact error.

Comment: there's no php here

Comment: Can you post the CREATE TABLE statement you used?

Comment: I did not write a CREATE TABLE statement.. I use the 'create table' area at the bottom of the database 'structure' view in phpmyadmin, and then went and defined the settings for each field manually.  for the 'symbol' field, it is defined as VARCHAR(255), no default value, utf8_general_ci, with 'adjust privileges' checked... all other settings are blank

Comment: Ok. Try going to the SQL tab and doing 'DESCRIBE tokens' and post the output.

Comment: going off your line of thinking, i copied the table to a new name, renamed the original to something else, then renamed the copy to the original name.  then the insert worked.  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format with backticks is
INSERT INTO `tokens` (`symbol`) VALUES ('XYZ');

FYI, I tried your first query on my server and worked fine so might be a problem with table structure.